# Using python to run different files (stata, .stc, etc), as you would a .bat on windows

Tags: python, batch-file, subprocess

In [this guide](http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/matthew.gentzkow/research/CodeAndData.pdf) to not being a total mess doing research, the authors talk about using a .py file to execute a directory in order -- that is, delete all the output files (.pdf, .txt, etc) and run just the .py and everything will be recreated from the raw data, stata files, maybe other .py's, etc etc.

What is the best way to do this in Python? I know one option is to use subprocesses, but is that the only option? Basically, how can I best mimic a .bat file using Python on a Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly use Python for shell-script type stuff - with the bonus that it will be relatively portable.

Another option you could consider is "BASH" "(The Bourne Again SHell). That will do everything you can do with .BAT files (and much more). Search for BASH shell scripting.

Whether Python or BASH is the right tool for the job depends on whether you're mostly just writing glue (to call a bunch of other programs) or if you're actually writing complex logic yourself. If it's the former, then I'd go with BASH.

Comment: If you bring up Terminal on your Mac, you will (almost certainly) be presented with a BASH prompt.

Comment: Using `bash` would then give you something that cannot run on Windows without Cygwin or some other add-on installed. Stick with Python and run the same code just about anywhere.

Comment: @Paul - Windows doesn't typically come with Python, either. There are lots of options for getting BASH on Windows - Cygwin, MinGW, win-bash (stand-alone port). Given the OP wants to do source control type stuff, there's a possibility he'll be using GIT - in which case the Windows installer will give you a BASH environment for free.